# Aggregation using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, group-by

I have a `string` of characters (eg. `A0009B80000J31500435`). Is there a way of creating a LINQ dictionary that groups the 0's and only shows one entry? The output I need is the following:

```
format: <index, character>
<0,A>
<1,0>
<4,9>
<5,B>
<6,8>
<7,0>
<11,J>
...
```

Comment: Is it only `0`s that get grouped up? If there were two consecutive `9`s, would that mean one entry in the dictionary or two?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` *loop* (not *Linq*) should do:

```
  string source = "A0009B80000J31500435";

  Dictionary<int, char> result = new Dictionary<int, char>();

  for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
    if (i == 0 || source[i] != '0' || source[i - 1] != '0')
      result.Add(i, source[i]);
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
[0, A]
[1, 0]
[4, 9]
[5, B]
[6, 8]
[7, 0]
[11, J]
[12, 3]
[13, 1]
[14, 5]
[15, 0]
[17, 4]
[18, 3]
[19, 5]
```

**Edit:** Technically, we can invent *Linq* query here, say,

```
Dictionary<int, char> result = Enumerable
  .Range(0, source.Length)
  .Where(i => i == 0 || source[i] != '0' || source[i - 1] != '0')
  .ToDictionary(i => i, i => source[i]);
```

by I doubt if it's a better code.

**Edit 2:** It seems that you want to compress `\0` (*zero* character) not `'0'` (*digit* zero), see comments below; if it's your case

```
  string source = "A\0\0\09B8\0\0\0\0J315\0\0435";

  Dictionary<int, char> result = new Dictionary<int, char>();

  for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
    if (i == 0 || source[i] != '\0' || source[i - 1] != '\0')
      result.Add(i, source[i]);
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid loops, since my string could be veeeeeery long.

Comment: i'd do it similar, but your answer doesnt match the title, "HOW TO DO IT WITH LINQ". if i'd answer like this i'd get downvoted faster than i could press submit. Maybe you should add a linq version.

Comment: @user2729463: willy-nilly you have to *loop* over the string (with explicit `for` or with implict `IEnumerator<T>` in case of Linq)

Comment: It doesn't seem to group them.

Comment: @user2729463: we don't have to *group* all consequent `0` and then *take* 1st item from the group: we can just take the 1st `0` and *skip* consequent `0`s

Comment: I'm trying it on the following character sequence: "MZ       ÿÿ" and the function returns index 5, 6 and 7 all having '0'. I'm expecting <5,0><8,0>

Comment: @user2729463: sorry, don't follow you: `"MZ ÿÿ"` has `5` characters only; it doesn't have `'0'` at all. so the answer is `[0, M]
[1, Z]
[2,  ]
[3, ÿ]
[4, ÿ]`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the blank spaces you see are 0x00. I need to group those.

Comment: @user2729463 is that a coincidence that "MZ ÿÿ" looks like the very beginning of a .exe executable, or are you somehow parsing executables via LINQ?

Comment: Its' a coincidence.

Comment: @user2729463: Do you have `"MZ ÿÿ\0\0\0\0\0"` and you want to get rid of `\0`, not `0` character? And why the answer is `<5,0><8,0>`, not `<5,0>`?
Do, actually, want to put the *first* as well as the *last* ocurrence in the group?

Comment: Ideally speaking, I'd only like the first occurrence, therefore if my string is "MZ ÿÿ    R", I'd expect to see <0,M><1,Z><2,\0><3,ÿ><4,ÿ><5,\0><9,R>

Comment: Any more ideas?